# Parse an XML file iand save output as a .csv file

Tags: r, xml

Parse an XML file in R, save output as a .csv file

Hi! I would like to parse the below section of a .xml file. I would like to extract the 6 x and y values for each of the 32 different regions (e.g. Africa_Eastern) and for the years 2025 to 2050 in 5-year time steps (I only include the year 2025 in the example below). Ideally the code should run in R and I would like the output to be stored in a .csv file. Unfortunately, I don't know the first thing about parsing an xml file so I am kindly asking whether someone here could write the code for me? (I hope that's a reasonable ask).
Many thanks in advance!

```
</CostCurves>
        <CostCurves year="2025">
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Africa_Eastern period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>1.85483</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.68375</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.55018</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.43327</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.35749</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Africa_Northern period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.41122</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>11.015</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>14.2121</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>17.3623</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>20.6647</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Africa_Southern period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>1.72179</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.39458</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.89463</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.31783</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.70338</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Africa_Western period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>1.98133</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.16525</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.30209</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.4147</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>6.55008</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Argentina period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.46248</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.76609</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.09012</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>6.47805</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.96966</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Australia_NZ period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.36735</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.78832</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>8.48494</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>11.7093</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>15.9495</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Brazil period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.24604</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>10.7526</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>13.7742</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>16.4745</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>19.1559</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Canada period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.10346</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>8.76402</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>12.4991</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>16.695</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>21.58</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Central America and Caribbean period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.43419</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.58947</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.83438</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>6.10992</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.55619</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Central Asia period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.48242</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>13.6719</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>21.0048</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>29.1153</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>38.3079</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>China period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>231.654</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>385.955</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>511.847</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>621.344</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>744.335</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Colombia period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>1.46305</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.46831</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.37408</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.1249</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.77753</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>EU-12 period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>10.9613</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>18.3857</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>24.8289</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>30.8324</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>37.7113</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>EU-15 period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>18.1314</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>32.5483</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>47.5484</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>63.8707</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>82.861</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Europe_Eastern period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.25238</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.52048</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.80754</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>10.2922</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>13.3114</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Europe_Non_EU period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.57803</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>12.5709</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>16.6713</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>20.4235</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>24.4984</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>European Free Trade Association period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0.526583</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0.951852</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>1.37125</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>1.81188</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.31756</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>India period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>79.0396</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>131.468</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>177.508</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>220.015</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>264.28</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Indonesia period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>8.98832</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>14.4115</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>18.567</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>21.8447</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>25.1198</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Japan period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.83514</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>12.7078</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>17.0009</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>21.0022</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>25.3945</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Mexico period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.04982</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>6.83851</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>9.60604</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>12.4243</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>15.7233</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Middle East period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>16.4526</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>25.4957</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>34.8797</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>44.8966</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>55.457</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Pakistan period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.23812</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.83479</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.47361</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.12261</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>8.89895</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Russia period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>18.9125</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>34.9933</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>53.4767</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>74.0363</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>96.8596</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>South Africa period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.51533</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>9.27159</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>12.8155</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>16.5462</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>21.2793</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>South America_Northern period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>1.32742</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.88209</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.28208</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.3518</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>6.59964</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>South America_Southern period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>3.30356</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.04217</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>6.52138</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.87436</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>9.4426</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>South Asia period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.05933</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>6.4968</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>9.05758</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>11.6193</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>14.1928</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>South Korea period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.61966</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>8.14913</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>11.3759</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>14.4751</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>18.1204</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Southeast Asia period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>17.1741</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>29.6944</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>40.9425</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>51.3549</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>62.3405</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>Taiwan period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>2.47746</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>4.25997</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>5.81793</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>7.17505</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>8.58906</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
            <Curve type="PointSetCurve">
                <title>USA period cost curve</title>
                <numericalLabel>6</numericalLabel>
                <PointSet type="ExplicitPointSet">
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>0</x>
                        <y>0</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>27.3644</x>
                        <y>33.2586</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>50.9304</x>
                        <y>66.5172</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>76.9715</x>
                        <y>99.7758</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>106.984</x>
                        <y>133.034</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                    <DataPoint type="XYDataPoint">
                        <x>144.804</x>
                        <y>166.293</y>
                    </DataPoint>
                </PointSet>
            </Curve>
        </CostCurves>
```

I tried to write some code in R but I am stuck at actually extracting the x, y value pairs:

```
install.packages("XML") 
library("XML")  
setwd("C:/path/to/folder")  
dataset <- xmlParse("file_name.xml")   
xy <- xmlToDataFrame(node=getNodeSet(dataset, "//CostCurves//title//DataPoint//x")); 
xy
```

Comment: Edit: I tried to write some code in R but I am stuck at actually extracting the x, y value pairs: ```# install.packages("XML")

library("XML")

setwd("C:/path/to/folder")

dataset <- xmlParse("file_name.xml")


xy <- xmlToDataFrame(node=getNodeSet(dataset, "//CostCurves//title//DataPoint//x")); xy
```

Comment: Your XML-file hasn't a simply structure and ```XML``` library (maybe) could't help you. Take a look at ```xml2```.